# Group specific child components React

Tags: reactjs

Currently im trying to render an info-card using React like this:

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const StyledInfoCard = styled.div`
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 flex-wrap: wrap;

 figure {
  margin: 0 1.5rem 0 0;
 }
`;

 const InfoCard = ({ children }) => <StyledInfoCard>{children}</StyledInfoCard>;

InfoCard.propTypes = {
 children: PropTypes.string.isRequired
};

/**
 * @component
 */
export default InfoCard;
```

The children contains three components:

```
<InfoCard>
 <Avatar alt="profile image Jonathan" source="https://images.pexels.com/photos/220453/pexels-photo-220453.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260"/>
 <Title size='xSmall' text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit" />
 <subTitle size='xSmall' text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit" />
</InfoCard>
```

My goal is to render the components like this:

```
<div>
 <figure>
  <img .../>
 </figure>
 <div>
  <h2>....</h2>
  <h3>.....</h3>
 </div>
</div>
```

So the child components contain a wrapper except the `<avatar>` component

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming each of the children components `Avatar`, `Title` and `subTitle` are composed of single nodes, shouldn't this work:

```
<InfoCard>
  <Avatar
    alt="profile image Jonathan"
    source="https://images.pexels.com/photos/220453/pexels-photo-220453.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260"
  />
  <div>
    <Title size="xSmall" text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit" />
    <subTitle size="xSmall" text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit" />
  </div>
</InfoCard>
```

If you want to maintain the structure in which `children` is passed then you can modify `InfoCard` :

```
const InfoCard = ({ children }) => {
  const containedNodes = [];
  const outerNodes = [];
  React.Children.forEach(children, child => {
    if (child.type === Avatar) {
      outerNodes.push(child);
    } else {
      containedNodes.push(child);
    }
  });
  return (
    <StyledInfoCard>
      {outerNodes}
      <div>{containedNodes}</div>
    </StyledInfoCard>
  );
};
```

Comment: Yes that would work but i dont want to change my 'structure'

<InfoCard>
      <Avatar/>
      <Title/>
      <subTitle/>
</InfoCard>

Only the output

Comment: @RonaldZwiers Updated answer

Comment: Thanks that worked when containedNodes.push(child) and not null

Comment: Oh !! Missed that. Updated !!